# magento infinite loop or memory leak after login

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am using booking module in my Magento store. All works fine before a while but after uploading products i start to face the **out of memory error**. All products created manually not by importing, Note i'm creating bundle products using custom product type "bookable".

After creating product from backend,Now i tried to login page starts to swing and it throws fatal error like below,

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 188219392) (tried to allocate 81 bytes) in * /public_html/demo/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 166


Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 181927936) (tried to allocate 3260 bytes) in * /public_html/demo/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php on line 204

PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 217055232) (tried to allocate 81 bytes) in * /public_html/demo/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 290
```

I change memory limit upto **512MB.** no luck with that

I found a fix, while i disable booking module, then works fine. after that i enable everything works good. But i want to figure out where bug is from. How can i find this issue. It eats my whole day.

Please some one guide the good way,

Edit:-

http://awesomescreenshot.com/067tfej14

I enabled Xdebug to check memory leak. please can any one tell where this is happen.

Comment: every time works good. After adding product only this one happens any guess where the hell will trigger after adding new products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem !

The whole hell was with my database. It was totally damaged with indexing problem while i migrate the database to local to live i missed to add bellow code

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; // add at the starting of mysql file

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; // add at the end of mysql file
```

So i had constrain problem in my database. Finally i out this and i luckily found the tool to repair the database [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool)!.

Whole nightmare comes to end ! Hope it will help some one